# Google Cloud Datastore - Different results of query by Kind and query by GQL

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql

I have 2 types of query, by Kind and by GQL

```
$query = $datastore
         ->query()
         ->kind('files')
         ->filter('tags','=','texture')
         ->filter('tags','=','newspaper')
         ->start($pageCursor);
```

This gives more results than GQL query:

```
$query = $datastore
         ->gqlQuery
         ("SELECT * 
           FROM files
           where tags='texture' and tags='newspaper'",
           ['allowLiterals' => true]
         );
```

Why are their results not the same?

My results of query by Kind: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r-Tonqs1ld4bKo0woIcR_UrMUTc1em0D

If I use query by GQL, only 4 results are found

**Update**
You can follow this topic: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/issues/1696

Comment: It could be something related to cursor that you have provided in query by kind. Have you tried removing that? Or try adding offset in your GQL query.

Comment: @Abhishek I have total 10 records for this query, query by Kind working well but query by GQL is not. GQL only give me 4 results

Comment: Can you remove cursor from datastore query and try?

Comment: Yes, I have removed cursor but nothing change

Comment: Could you provide the minimal data for reproducing the two different results? It seems that the two queries are identical. I tried several different entries and I’m getting the same results with both queries.

Comment: Hello @GuillermoCacheda, I have added the link to results of query by Kind. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: @LãoCòi I have reproduced your issue with the example data that you provided and the following entity structure: ["name/ID", "tags", "title"]. And I got the same result from both queries. Could confirm if you are using the same datastore structure or provide the one that you are using?

Comment: @llompalles Yes, I'm using the same structure as you. Do you make the query on Google Cloud Console or php script? I have the problem when make query with php

Comment: @LãoCòi Yes, it's the same result with both methods, here is the php code that I've used: https://pastebin.com/svfTJmsd

Comment: @LãoCòi Did my code work for you?

Comment: @llompalles Sorry for late response, I have tried your code but problem not fixed. The count of results is 19 and 4 :(

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to find your error without seeing your code, try to provide more details in your next questions.

I have used your example and all works as expected. The output of this script is:

`Query by kind retrieves 19 results 
 Query by GQL  retrieves 19 results`

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient;
# Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
$projectId = 'YOUR-PROJECT-ID';

$datastore = new DatastoreClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId
]);

$titles = ['man sitting near door', 'way reading paper', 'scattered magazines', 'grayscale ', 'photography of kanji text', 'texture: vintage newspaper', 'wall floor recycle light simple', 'old newspaper texture', 'Mockup Old Paper Color  ', 'Mockup Journal.', 'Old Newspaper Texture', 'Triangle Geometric Graphic Pattern Template', 'paperboard carton surface beige plain', 'paperboard simple fiber dusty texture', 'Designer Workspace', 'craft texture brown journal note', 'Brown texture', 'Newspaper collage texture', 'Texture Newspaper'];

$tags = ['newspaper, texture, space for copy, space, cover, white, textured, antique, text, press, write, worn, backdrop, surface, old, scratch, brown, ancient, light, background, vintage, effect, letter, space for text, template, blank, rough, color, line, book, pattern, stain, paper, design, copy, dirty, grunge, copyspace, aged, retro, banner, abstract, message, print, smudge, material, grungy, wooden, wall, age, chinese, china, chinese newspaper', 
    'world, war, newspaper, texture, history, grunge, pattern, american, war, battle', 'basket, yellow building, shop, colour, wallpaper, texture, misc, wallpaper, urban, bicycle, morning, sidewalk, asian, newspaper, yellow, street, bike, man, tree, china, bycicle', 
    'man, boy, male, card, paper, decoration, woman, child, smile, torn, wall, paper, poster, texture, old, affiche wall advert wallpaper portugal wall poster erosion used print urban, newspaper', 
    'white, cloud, house, bw, black and white, pattern, light, street, silhouette, texture, calligraphy, composition, japanese, japan, newspaper, character, wall, wall paper, wall art, poster, black and white, png images', 
    'newspaper, texture, space for copy, space, cover, white, textured, antique, text, press, write, worn, backdrop, surface, old, scratch, brown, ancient, light, background, vintage, effect, letter, space for text, template, blank, rough, color, line, book, pattern, stain, paper, design, copy, dirty, grunge, copyspace, aged, retro, banner, abstract, message, print, smudge, material, grungy, wooden, wall, vintage newspaper', 
    'background, pattern, vintage, texture, paper, light, space, grunge, wall, note, flat, old paper, paper texture, desk, newspaper, recycle, natural, document, nature background, clean', 
    'newspaper, texture, space for copy, space, cover, white, textured, antique, text, press, write, worn, backdrop, surface, old, scratch, brown, ancient, light, background, vintage, effect, letter, space for text, template, blank, rough, color, line, book, pattern, stain, paper, design, copy, dirty, grunge, copyspace, aged, retro, banner, abstract, message, print, smudge, material, grungy, wooden, wall, age, old paper', 
    'newspaper, cut, paper, kraft, cardboard, mockup, old, slip, ad, advertisement, advertising, ancient, announcement, antique, backdrop, background, banner, blank, border, card, christmas, communication, design, dirty, edge, empty, grunge, illustration, information, label, letter, message, note, page, parchment, pattern, poster, red, ripped, shadow, sticker, tag, template, texture, torn, vector, vintage, wallpaper, web, white', 
    'leather, magazine, mockup, book, black, spread, page, double, brochure, blank, reading, journal, template, a4, holding, hand, newspaper, front, leaflet, person, back, binding, softcover, big, pamphlet, album, business, clear, dark, design, desk, display, document, glossy, grey, hard, hardcover, layout, ledger, mag, mock up, news, opened, paper, paperback, print, sheet, showing, soft, text, texture', 
    'newspaper, texture, space for copy, space, cover, white, textured, antique, text, press, write, worn, backdrop, surface, old, scratch, brown, ancient, light, background, vintage, effect, letter, space for text, template, blank, rough, color, line, book, pattern, stain, paper, design, copy, dirty, grunge, copyspace, aged, retro, banner, abstract, message, print, smudge, material, grungy, wooden, wall, age',
    'pattern, people, texture, template, geometric, paint, home, triangle, geometric pattern, graphic, kid, child, square, bag, person, paper texture, window, creative, newspaper, plants',
    'background, pattern, vintage, texture, paper, light, space, grunge, wall, note, flat, old paper, paper texture, desk, newspaper, recycle, natural, document, nature background, clean',
    'background, pattern, vintage, texture, paper, light, space, grunge, wall, note, flat, old paper, paper texture, desk, newspaper, recycle, natural, document, nature background, clean',
    'designer, table, workspace, computer, flat, object, workstation, desktop, design, work, office, home, desk, display, lamp, concept, cup, decor, modern, illustration, monitor, interior, inside, house, education, job, book, coffee, business, light, style, background, graphic, workplace, icons, symbol, elements, equipment, emblem, lifestyle, place, decorative, collection, room, set, organization, stylish, freelance, notepad, creative, jobs, creativity, mug, email, view, bulb, tablet, notebook, top, wood, number, texture, newspaper, think, paper, talk, bubble, mock-up, speech, item, media, template, idea, management, mock, project, mail, infographic, connect, wooden, chat, icon, content, pc, space, minimalism, vector, technology, web, screen, website, white, corporate, decorated, mouse, internet, process, clock',
    'background, pattern, vintage, texture, paper, light, space, grunge, wall, note, flat, old paper, paper texture, desk, newspaper, recycle, natural, document, nature background, clean',
    'pattern, vintage, texture, paper, light, space, grunge, wall, note, flat, old paper, paper texture, desk, newspaper, vintage pattern, recycle, natural, document, clean, floor',
    'newspaper, texture, collage, news, old, background, text, book',
    'newspaper, texture, space for copy, space, cover, white, textured, antique, text, press, write, worn, backdrop, surface, old, scratch, brown, ancient, light, background, vintage, effect, letter, space for text, template, blank, rough, color, line, book, pattern, stain, paper, design, copy, dirty, grunge, copyspace, aged, retro, banner, abstract, message, print, smudge, material, grungy, wooden, wall'];

$i = 0;
foreach ($titles as $title){
    $entity = $datastore->entity('Examples');
    $entity['title'] = $title;
    $entity['tags'] = explode(", ", $tags[$i]);
    $datastore->insert($entity);
    $i = $i + 1; 
}

sleep(1);

$query = $datastore
         ->query()
         ->kind('Examples')
         ->filter('tags','=','texture')
     ->filter('tags','=','newspaper');

$results = $datastore->runQuery($query);

$count = 0;
foreach ($results as $res) {
    $count++;
}
echo 'Query by kind retrieves ', $count, ' results', PHP_EOL ;


$query = $datastore
         ->gqlQuery
         ("SELECT * 
           FROM Examples
           where tags='texture' and tags='newspaper'",
           ['allowLiterals' => true]
         );

$results = $datastore->runQuery($query);

$count = 0;
foreach ($results as $res) {
    $count++;
}
echo 'Query by GQL retrieves ' ,$count, ' results', PHP_EOL;
```